# Isolating Bi-Colored LED from MCU/Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, led, opto-isolator

I'm currently trying to implement an opto-isolator into my project currently I have my code to run perfectly with out the implementation, but I was wondering how I can effectively control my RG LED (which I am restricted to using a common cathode)

I know my schematic is wonky :p I was just trying to properly interface my opto-coupler before I change my schematic.

**Basically I want to know if there is a way to control the RG LEDs based on if I output from my Green or Red terminal of the Arduino with one optocoupler.** 
(I will be implementing up to 12 RG LEDs and have a few 4-channel isolators)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Red and Green are shorted? I imagine these are MCU outputs? Are you sure it is working?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. Red and Green are completely separate pins from my Arduino

i.e.
Red = pins A0~A11
Green = pins 2~13

Comment: Which is exactly the problem I am talking about. You are *shorting* them.

Comment: Why do you want to optoisolate LEDs? You can't control 2 LEDs independently with a single opto. (+ the short that Eugene mentioned)

Comment: I see what you're saying. In this schematic, yes. I should have drawn it a little more clearly. I'm asking for another manipulation to control either or (you're free to make suggestions on schematics, sorry.

Comment: If you are asking about a circuit, the schematic should reflect it exactly. Otherwise we just don't have a common base.

Comment: Get rid of the opto and drive the red & green directly.

Comment: You are lighting 4 LEDs when you actually want to light one, there are some random pull up/down resistors, a short and an unneeded opto (unless you explain why you need it). I don't know where to start making suggestions.

Comment: @WesleyLee and brhans I just want to know if there is way to implement the isolator to separate my LEDs from the Arduino.

Prior to the isolator I was just sinking the RG LEDs to my Arduino, but I was told that I should use an isolator

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry I'm new to the board I will take the schematic off to take away the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

With one isolater like that, triggering either channel will light both LEDs.

Comment: Yes, I am asking if there is a way to isolate and control the bi-color LED with another schematic

Comment: You will need one isolater per LED.  If your LEDs didn't have common cathodes, you could look into 'charlieplexing' to reduce part count.

Comment: Depending on your application, you could replace the opto-isolaters with MOSFETs to save money.  You would still need one per LED.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking into charlieplexing, but you're right the common cathodes gave me some issues

Answer (score 0):

Drive the LEDs directly.

Which means one of the following:

Left one means one LED per I/O. You get independent control of each LED.

Right one (won't work in your case, I missed that you had common cathode, sorry) means that you control both LEDs at the same time, but they will be at opposite states. When pin is driven low, one LED is on, the other is OFF and vice versa.

I didnt use optos because you still havent explained why they are necessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEUdtt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The left image is what I had originally had in my schematic, thanks @WesleyLee was there a reason for why you had sourced your diode? I was informed that it would be a better design to sink it.

Comment: @dm41nes - the schematic you originally had on the question looked very different than the one on the left. The diodes are on that orientation because you mentioned they are common cathode. If sinking you can only turn both of them at the same time. Some ICs have much higher sink current than source, in those cases sinking would be better. That's not the case with the Arduino.